# Google Apps Script not retrieving information from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with information about users in each row, and the first column of each row is the ID of the user. I am trying to search through the spreadsheet for an ID someone enters and retrieve the information about the user with that ID. I have achieved a proof of concept with this with much simpler data, but now the script simply doesn't return any information. My function for retrieving the information from the spreadsheet is below. Any thought?

```
//Determines which request the user wants to approve/deny based on the ID they enter.
function getRequestFromSheet(id){
//Gets the info as an array from the spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('*spreadsheets ID*');
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var range = sht.getRange(1, 1, sht.getLastRow(), sht.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  //Initially assumes the user entered an invalid request ID
  var row = -1;
  var rowData = [];

  //Searches for the ID the user entered in the spreadsheet.
  for(var i=0; i<range.length;i++){
    if(id == parseInt(range[i][0])){
      row = i;
    }
  }

  //Returns the variable data to the function changeInfo.
  if(row != -1){
      rowData = range[row];
  }
  else
      rowData = ['', 'INVALID ID', 'INVALID ID'];
  return rowData;

}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the sheet? Is the first column (ID) text or a number in your sheet? The ID your send to the function is number?

Comment: Your code works for me, using plain numbers.  Try converting the `rowData` array to a string, `return rowData.toString();` and see if that makes any difference.  Apps Script won't return an object from the server.

Comment: It is a number in the sheet. I currently have it set up so that if the script cannot match an ID the user entered to one in the spreadsheet, it will display a warning (I have successfully tested this). When I enter an ID I know is in the spreadsheet, nothing happens. No warning that the ID couldn't be found. The spreadsheet does have over 50 columns, not sure if that would matter...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Returns the variable data to the function changeInfo.
  if (row != -1){
    for(var j=0; j<range[row].length; j++){
       rowData[j] = range[row][j].toString(); 
    }
  }
  else
      rowData = ['', 'INVALID ID', 'INVALID ID'];
```

This works. Thank you Sandy Good.